# Filtro de Angular no actualiza la vista después de actualizar el modelo

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Creé un filtro personalizado, acá está mi vista de prueba:

```
<div>{{ 1400956671914 | userDate }}</div>
<div>{{ 1288323623006 | userDate }}</div>
```

Éste está basado en el filtro de Angular y asigna el formato personalizado de fecha desde las preferencias del usuario:

```
app.filter('userDate', function ($filter, userModel) {

  var userDate = userModel.getPreferences().dateFormat;
  // userDate = 'yyyy-mm-dd'

  function userDateFilter (date) {
    return $filter('date')(date, userDate);
  };

  return userDateFilter;

});
```

Éste es el resultado:

```
2014-05-24
2010-10-28
```

Tengo una vista (Mi Perfil) donde se actualiza el userModel y asigna un nuevo formato de fecha dateFormat a 'dd/mm/yyyy'. Luego al regresar a mi vista de prueba ésta no se ha actualizado:

```
2014-05-24
2010-10-28
```

Tengo que presionar `f5` para ver los cambios esperados:

```
24/05/2014
28/10/2010
```

¿Cómo puedo escuchar el cambio en el modelo para actualizar el filtro?

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo donde se actualiza userModel dentro de "MI Perfil"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que el userDate format estaba siendo capturado en la función userDateFilter. Ésta no cambia si las preferencias de usuario cambian. Lo que se debe hacer es recuperar el formato de fecha del usuario cuando el filtro es ejecutado. Escribiéndolo de la siguiente manera funcionó:

```
app.filter('userDate', function ($filter, userModel) {
   function userDateFilter (date) {
      return $filter('date')(date, userModel.getPreferences().dateFormat);
   };
   return userDateFilter;
});
```